# Xero API: Issues with pulling unrealized gain and loss over webservice

Tags: xero-api

We are currently having a difference when loading data via Webservice / Rest from Xero to our own software:LucaNet and it is specifically from unrealized / realized gain and losses from Foreign currency. The reason being is that those values are being calculated by xero but not being posted as a transaction while we are pulling transactions from Xero to LucaNet. Hence we have a few differences in the Balance Sheet and PnL on some GL Accounts. Specifically Bank Accounts and PnL accounts for unrealized gain / losses.
Does anyone have an idea on that?
Help would be much appreciated.

BR
Andy

Comment: Any luck finding answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

this issue sounds best answered by diving into the specific data of a request. The best forum for that is likely the Xero API tech support team.

You can start a case by emailing `api@xero.com` - include your client id and formatted data related to the discrepancy.